# Pipe a stream to Debug.Write()

Tags: c#, .net, stream, stdout

I am running a command line utility using `Process.Start`. For debugging purposes I would like to have its output stream to Visual Studio's Debug Output panel  (`Debug.Write`). I'd like to do this in real time rather than waiting for the process to complete and then writting it all at once.

I know this is possible in theory but I'm not experienced enough with the `Stream` object to know how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it puts you on the right track, I think.

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Then, your event handler for receiving data.

```
void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write(e.Data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir - that's it exactly. Just one note, you can't use this technique AND  `p.StandardOuptut.ReadToEnd()` You have to create a `StringBuilder` and build it up yourself in the event handler. Easy enough, just something to be aware of.

Comment: How can we pipe a custom data, such as a % of data processed to p_OutputDataReceived from calling scope