# How to parse a third party console application showing the status of external process (C#)?

Tags: c#, process, console, streamreader

The following video (gif) shows a third party console application that is managing an external process.

[image]

I'm looking to parse the information in the standard output to show it in a WinForm (C#).

I tried various approaches (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579922/c-sharp-show-output-of-process-in-real-time)) but none seems to work, meaning nothing in the StreamReader, neither OutputDataReceived event.

If the text have new line characters, there is not issue. But is not the case with this app.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use ReadLine() so you wait until you get an entire line before doing any processing.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thanks for your feedback. I tried your suggestion but the application is not sending the "end of line" character in order to allow ReadLine or OutputDataReceived work properly

Comment: It there a different terminating character?

Comment: I don't know because I don't have the source code. Perhaps similar approaches as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app

Comment: Then reverse engineer the data.  Capture data and put into text (hex) so you can resolve the issue.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415655/2330053).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by reverse engineer the data.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thanks for your feedback. That proposal works only when there is new line character. Already tried.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the operating system. But it looks like the [line gets rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888533/how-can-i-update-the-current-line-in-a-c-sharp-windows-console-app). In this case you would need to read the stream buffer before it gets "committed" by a newline. (As you found out. IISC, the answer you linked uses BeginOutput***ReadLine***.)
So, when you have your stream (e.g. [standard input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.openstandardinput?view=net-5.0)?) You might be able to read the buffer [more precisely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=net-5.0).

Hope, I got the question right :)